# React App: How to implement Facebook Login?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I know that `react-facebook-login` and `react-facebook` exists. Nonetheless, I want to implement it my own way and I am stuck there.

In my index.html I have the following:

```
  <body>
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
     <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v5.0&appId=???&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>
....
```

My React function looks like this:

```
/* global FB */
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Connect() {
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      console.log("logged in");
    } else {
      console.log("not logged in")
    }
  }

  function checkLoginState() {
    window.FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      window.FB.init({
        appId      : '????',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v5.0',
      });

      window.FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
        statusChangeCallback(response);        // Returns the login status.
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v5.0&appId=????";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  });

  return (
      <div
        className="fb-login-button"
        data-width=""
        data-size="large"
        data-button-type="continue_with"
        data-auto-logout-link="false"
        data-use-continue-as="false"
      />
  );
}
```

The Facebook login button is rendered. When I try to click on it while logged into Facebook I get the message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at Object.prepareCall (sdk.js?hash=3051e31de39c8b328cfbd1efcce7f613&ua=modern_es6:145)
...
```

When I am in private browser mode and click on it, then the login dialog opens up. When I enter my user credentials it just exists and nothing happens.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Embedding the SDK with parameters in the URL hash makes it automatically initialize when it has loaded, the `fbAsyncInit` should not even fire any more in that case. You need to use one of those ways - URL hash parameters, _or_ `fbAsyncInit`/`FB.init` - not both at the same time, that is asking for trouble.